# java error : constructor is already defined in class - using lombok

Tags: java, lombok

The error

```
java: constructor Restaurant() is already defined in class  
com.example.order_system.domain.Restaurant
```

appear when I add this class and run the program

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Restaurant {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @NotEmpty(message = "The restaurant must have a name")
    private String name;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Please add a description for this restaurant")
    private String description;

    @NotEmpty(message = "The restaurant must have a location")
    private String location;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "restaurant", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<ContactDetails> contactDetails = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Comment: You might have another Restaurant constructor with the same signature, perhaps inside another package.

Comment: `@RequiredArgsConstructor` checks for uninitialized `final` and `@NotNull` fields, not for `@NotEmpty` ones, so it's probably just generating another no-arguments constructor.

Comment: @ASH thanks for your answer, but the correct answer is as it explained in the answers section below

Comment: In this case you may want to use the `@Data` annotation anyway. It combines `@RequiredArgsConstructor`, `@Getter`, `@Setter`, `@ToString` and additionally `@EqualsAndHashCode` which is always a good idea for entities.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As mentioned in [documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor) @RequiredArgsConstructor is built using `final` fields:

> @RequiredArgsConstructor generates a constructor with 1 parameter for
> each field that requires special handling. All non-initialized final
> fields get a parameter, as well as any fields that are marked as
> @NonNull that aren't initialized where they are declared. For those
> fields marked with @NonNull, an explicit null check is also generated.
> The constructor will throw a NullPointerException if any of the
> parameters intended for the fields marked with @NonNull contain null.
> The order of the parameters match the order in which the fields appear
> in your class.

So either remove @RequiredArgsConstructor annotation or mark some of fields with `final` keyword (or @NonNull annotation).

Answer (score 5):

Try to change @RequiredArgsConstructor to @AllArgsConstructor and that's been fine.
See more in [documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor)

Answer (score 1):

In my scenario, an empty class was present throwing the same above error, removing all the constructor based annotations i.e. `@AllArgsConstructor and @NoArgsConstructor`, solved the issue for me.